# Postgres generate_series wrong result

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I don't know if it's a bug or it's intended, but the simple query

```
select generate_series('2021-03-28'::date, '2021-03-29'::date - interval '1 minute', interval '1 hour') as date_hour;

> 2021-03-28 00:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 01:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 03:00:00.000 <---
  2021-03-28 03:00:00.000 <---
  2021-03-28 04:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 05:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 06:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 07:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 08:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 09:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 10:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 11:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 12:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 13:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 14:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 15:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 16:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 17:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 18:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 19:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 20:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 21:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 22:00:00.000
  2021-03-28 23:00:00.000
```

generates a duplicate row **2021-03-28 03:00:00.000**, as you can also see in the picture below.

What I'm missing here?

[image]

---

```
select version();

> PostgreSQL 14.4 (Ubuntu 14.4-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit
```

---

**UPDATE**

Despite the result, under the scene it looks like the values are correctly different. I wonder if it's just a representation issue.

```
select date_trunc('hour', date_hour), extract(epoch from date_hour), count(*)
from (
    select generate_series('2021-03-28'::date, '2021-03-29'::date - interval '1 minute', interval '1 hour') as date_hour
) s
group by date_trunc('hour', date_hour), extract(epoch from date_hour)
order by date_trunc('hour', date_hour), extract(epoch from date_hour)
```

[image]

Comment: You need until 29 day ?

Comment: @Nickname_used I've edited the question in order to list the full result. I need  only day 28. 24 rows total, from time 00:00 to time 23:00. The result is effectively 24 rows, but the time 02:00 is skipped and 03:00 is replicated.

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0de07ba61a955929cb935422a5c5181c)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name damn... I don't want to think my version is bugged for a such simple function.

Comment: In my pgsql same problem

Comment: I think this is a timezone-handling bug: 28th March 2021 was the day that [Summer Time began in most of Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_time_in_Europe), so at what would have been 2am the clocks jumped forward to 3am. That explains the _skip_, but not the _repeat_.

Comment: but problem only with your dates 03-28, 03-29 :
`select generate_series('2021-01-01'::date, '2021-01-02'::date - interval '1 minute', interval '1 hour') as date_hour` dont have this problem

Comment: @Nickname_used yes, but I need a range of a year in my real case scenario ;) I have just reduced the problem for SO

Comment: As IMSoP pointed: it is related to timezone, but not a bug. You alse miss hour 2  clock. A quick workaround in function could be to set timezone where there is not clock jump, like Venezuela.

Comment: What does `show TimeZone` show for you?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Europe/Berlin

Comment: @user_0 As I said, that explains the skip, but not the duplication - in no timezone should 3AM be one hour after 3AM, surely? (Unless there was a _backwards_ jump, but then you wouldn't have 2AM missing.) [Just using Europe/Berlin doesn't reproduce the bug](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0e07da6003c05a32d027b12e5141b837).

Comment: Using `timestamptz`insetad of `date`, I [get the output I would expect for a forward clock change](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4f1107d00698d741df5ea08a804ddf4a): 1AM followed by 3AM, then 4AM.

Comment: @IMSoP I think I get it now. The timestamptz solution is probably what I need to use my real scenario. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my PostgreSQL v15 database.